# How does Ultron create his body in Avengers: Age of Ultron?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers, avengers-age-of-ultron

In [trailer of Avengers: Age of Ultron](https://youtu.be/tmeOjFno6Do?t=18s), there a scene where you can see Ultron's hand covered in molten metal. It seems like Ultron is creating his body. But in the movie I couldn't find this scene.

[image: Ultron's hand dripping molten metal]

Is there any explanation given in the movie (that I probably have missed) on how did Ultron create his body?

Comment: How does Ultron create his body? *Very carefully.*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the opening fight scene of Age of Ultron, Stark notices some tables with robotics on them in Von Strucker's base while looking for the Scepter.

After Ultron is activated and escapes with one of Stark's drones, he returns to this facility to construct more bodies.

[image]

[Age of Ultron was originally over 3 hours long](https://www.businessinsider.com/avengers-age-of-ultron-was-originally-over-3-hours-2015-4). Whedon was forced to cut over an hour's worth of film to get it down to 142 minutes.

Comment: Any chance Marvel would release the 3 hour version in near future?

Comment: @Naveen you will probably have to wait for the limited director's cut criterion platinum edition.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, we do not actually see Ultron create his body. However, we know "how" he did it, even if it happened off-screen. The primary reason he went back to the abandoned HYDRA lab from the start of the movie was because that facility had the equipment he needed to create a body. He created that body in the same way he created the army of other bodies (once he got more Vibranium).

When he flees from the Avengers' mansion, he's still in a makeshift Iron Legion body. The next time we see him, the Maximov twins are approaching him in the church in Sokovia, and he's already using his new body.

Most likely, the scene from the trailer was cut due to time constraints.

Answer (score -1):

ultron used the vibranium that was already there. he must have used it to make another body. when he finally went into his new body. for more clearence, ultron flew back to the hydra lab (while still in a warped drone body) to get vibranium. then he made his body.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  This answer mostly duplicates an existing answer, and doesn't answer the question if (and when) this was detailed in the movie.  SE isn't a discussion site; you should only post an answer if you have new information to add.  Please consider taking the [tour].